# How do I start building API for an application?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, project

I am trying to build a currency exchange API using a third-party currency conversion API, which will allow users to sign up, sign in, and able to create, read, update user balance/wallet, and able to convert currency.

Can anyone guide how to start? I am planning to use Django and Django REST Framework and will test using POSTMAN?

Comment: May be start with the Django REST Framework tutorial? That is pretty self explanatory. Start with the normal APIView and see if you need something like GenericViews or Viewsets.

Comment: I tried using Django REST Frameworks - APIViews. But I am not able to frame the idea of how a user can create, read, update its user balance/wallet. Should I use Viewsets? Also, confused between when to use APIViews, Generic Views, and ViewSets?

Comment: The only difference I see between Generic Views and ViewSets is the ability to use `router`. Which simplify your url creation (which i don't like personally).

Comment: I would personally suggest you to just start writing APIViews as your MVP. 
I don't know about your data models and project details so can't say enough about the user flows. May be start with Read wallet balance API view. Then move to Create and Update, by the way you can achieve all three operations in a single APIView if you want.

Comment: This one is for ruby instead of python, but perhaps it could still be of help. https://github.com/sammyhenningsson/shaf

Comment: Okay, @SadanA. do you know any better resource where DRF has explained in a beginner level apart from the DRF documentation?